# How safe is it to delete a route? Would it cause problems?

Tags: networking, iproute

I currently have a route in my broken linux machine that does not show up in my working linux machine when I type in `ip route`.

I don't want the post to be duplicate so check my older threads.

Will deleting the route be useful or will it break my distro more?

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is ambiguous at best. We can not imagine what you consider as a _broken linux distro_ and  _broke_ is not a quantitative term. Something can not be **more** broken.  You need to give examples of your `ip route` command outputs from the good system and the broken system and explain why the broen system is, well, broken. what is it not doing that you want it to do ?

Comment: I would highly recommend reading up on [routing tables](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html). If you're accessing the server remotely I wouldn't recommend messing with the routing tables because you have a good chance of knocking yourself out.

Comment: It's not a server, it's my home computer. Also check my other questions it's described there.

Comment: Each question should be self-contained and answerable; link to a previous question if there's history that you think is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing network configuration can be done in two ways:

1. You can change the configuration files for your network and re-run the scripts that apply that configuration, or restart the service that manages the network (e.g., the `network-manager` service). This makes "permanent" changes, in that the change will be applied after your next reboot as well.
2. You can run commands that directly manipulate the kernel, rather than making changes in the configuration file; e.g., you could run something like `ip route del default`, which removes your default route (if there is only one default route, that is).

In the first case, if you do something wrong, then you are likely to cause issues for your installation that may be difficult to fix. In the second case, however, this is not true; all that's needed is to restart either the networking subsystem (with its unmodified configuration), or the computer as a whole, to get the old situation back.

If your computer is having trouble reaching the network, and it has a route that another computer on the same network which has no trouble reaching the network does not have, then yes, removing that route may be a good idea. This can be done with the `ip` command, too:

```
ip route del XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX via ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ
```

where `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX` is a network address, and `ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ` is the gateway for that route. If that fixes your problem, then change the network configuration and make the change permanent. If it *doesn't* fix your problem, simply reapply the old configuration by restarting the network subsystem or your computer as a whole.

Comment: OK and if I screw up how do I restart the network subsystem?

Comment: There is usually an init script or other service. That highly depends on the distribution you're using. But you can also just restart the whole system, if you're not sure...

Comment: And network config in Ubuntu/ Mint is in /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: The permanent configuration is there by default on debian, yes. I imagine Ubuntu and/or mint might install network-manager by default, though, in which case it isn't and you need to look at the network-manager configuration.

Comment: Deleting the route didn't change anything but I'm giving you credit for your good answer.